# Mockup tools Hebrew (RTL) support and compairision

Tags: sketchflow, mockup-tool

Looking for a mockup tool such as one listed in "[Balsamiq mockups alternative for building wireframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156937/balsamiq-mockups-alternative-for-building-wireframes)", "[What *collaborative* wireframing / UI mockup tools are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408202/what-collaborative-wireframing-ui-mockup-tools-are-out-there)" and "[Web UI prototyping tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720191/web-ui-prototyping-tools)"

However, I need a tool that will work with **Hebrew** and **Right to Left** screen orientation. I've checked [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) (web demo) and couldn't do Hebrew there.

Also looking for a comparision of such tools, including Sketchflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never properly tested it but I believe that [WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) handles Right to Left screen orientation. This is because it's based on Eclipse and Eclipse has a proper RTL support.

Answer (score 0):

Some RTL people do use http://MockupScreens.com, but I'm not sure whether for English or their native language. And I've never tested RTL to be frank.